# Chrome extension see if a video is running on yt

Tags: javascript, video, google-chrome-extension, youtube

I need my chrome extension to know if the video is playing or paused on YouTube. I noticed that in the following code (html code from YouTube) when I press play the "aria-label" switches from `Play` to `Pause`.
Is there a way to let my chrome extension know it?

```
<button class="ytp-play-button ytp-button" aria-label="Play">
    <svg height="100%" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 36 36" width="100%">
        <use class="ytp-svg-shadow" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#ytp-id-67"></use>
        <path class="ytp-svg-fill" d="M 12,26 18.5,22 18.5,14 12,10 z M 18.5,22,25,18,25,18 18.5,14 z" id="ytp-id-67"></path>
    </svg>
</button>
```

I also need to know the channel name, in this case it should be "iFunzio"

```
<a class="yt-simple-endpoint style-scope yt-formatted-string" href="/channel/UCunKgLgPHk-7C-0Dr9vXalQ">
    iFunzio
</a>
```

Possibly all of this running in client using js. 
Thanks to everyone who will help me!

Answer (score 0):

this code returns true if the aria-label is "Play" or false otherwise

```
document.getElementsByClassName("ytp-play-button")[0].getAttribute("aria-label")=="Play";
```

this code gets the channel name of the video you're currently watching:

```
document.getElementById("owner-container").querySelectorAll('[href*="/channel/"]')[0].innerHTML;
```

Comment: But i don’t have those code that i posted in my page, i copied them from youtube inspector page. I need to see them from a chrome extension. Do those code work too?

Comment: if you use the chrome extension correctly (i hope you know how to do that), and use the above 2 lines in the content.js file (the front-end javascript file), then it will work, yes.

Comment: it seems idk how to do that ahahah, I'm still learning how chrome extension work